# PHP display CheckBox values

Tags: php, forms, drupal, checkbox

I am working on a form in Drupal 6.  I have a checkbox value that I need to have show up after the user selects submit.  All the other fields populate on the screen but this one.  Here is my code for the checkBox:

```
$form['Questions']['Question3'] = array(
    '#description' => t('Please specify what departments you have been in contact with, if any.'),
    '#title' => t('3. Have you been in contact with other departments about this project?'),
    '#type' => 'checkboxes',

    '#options' => array(
      'Archival'=>t('Yes, I have requested archival materials'),
      'Conducting'=>t('Yes, I have been conducting research with'),
    ),
  );
```

Comment: Where are the rest of the codes? Do you mean that you want these checkboxes to appear after a user selects a value from a select list (that is not currently displayed here)?

Comment: Here is what I'm using for the output for all the other fields that use a textfield, or textarea. i'm just trying to figure out how to have this option / checkbox area to display the selected content.

Comment: $output .=  '<p><b>13.  Who will own the copyright of the completed work?   </b><br>'.$form_state['values']['Question13'] . '</p>';

Comment: Please, provide the whole form in your question otherwise I cannot understand what you mean at all!

Comment: here's the form element for the checkBox. . .

Comment: $form['Questions']['Question3'] = array(
    '#description' => t('Please specify what departments you have been in contact with, if any.'),
    '#title' => t('3. Have you been in contact with other departments about this project?'),
    '#type' => 'checkboxes',
 '#default_value'   => variable_get('Archival', 0),
   
  
   '#options' => array(
      'Archival'=>t('Yes, I have requested archival materials'),
      'Conducting'=>t('Yes, I have been conducting research with'),
    ),
  );